# SwiftUI | Dynamic Navigation Bar Title

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

**Hello,**
My app has a **TabView inside the only navigation view in the whole app**. To change the navigationTitle I use an extension that has a variable navigationBarTitle, that returnes different titles for every tab bar selection. Unfortunately, the whole "changing the title thing" stopped working a while back and I can't get it to update.

The switch inside is always called and returns correctly, but the navigation title doesn't change either way.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code

ContentView.swift

```
     NavigationView {
        TabView(selection: self.$viewModel.tabBarSelection) {
            ListView(viewModel: self.toProcessViewModel)
                .tabItem {
                    R.image.tabBar.toProcess
                    Text("tabbar.title.approval".localized)
                }
                .tag(0)
            
            ListView(viewModel: self.myRequestsViewModel)
                .tabItem {
                    R.image.tabBar.myRequests
                    Text("tabbar.title.myRequests".localized)
                }
                .tag(1)
            
            PasswordView()
                .tabItem {
                    R.image.tabBar.password
                    Text("tabbar.title.password".localized)
                }
                .tag(2)
                .commonRedimBackground()
            
            SettingsView(viewModel: self.settingsViewModel)
                .tabItem {
                    R.image.tabBar.settings
                    Text("tabbar.title.settings".localized)
                }
                .tag(3)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(navigationBarTitle), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(navigationBarHidden)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .accentColor(R.color.blue)
    }
```

ContentViewModel.swift

```
final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabBarSelection: Int = 0
}
```

ContentView-Extended

```
private extension ContentView { // For navigation
var navigationBarTitle: String {
    switch viewModel.tabBarSelection {
        case 0:
            return "tabbar.title.approval".localized
        case 1:
            return "tabbar.title.myRequests".localized
        case 2:
            return "" //"tabbar.title.password".localized - UIKit View - remove after switching to SwiftUI
        case 3:
            return "tabbar.title.settings".localized
        default:
            return "SELECTION_ERROR"
    }
}

var navigationBarHidden: Bool {
    switch self.viewModel.tabBarSelection {
        case 2:
            return true
        default:
            return false
    }
}
```

}

**Edit after Yrb's comment** - Unfortunately still not working

```
struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel

@ObservedObject var toProcessViewModel: ListViewModel = ListViewModel(listType: .toProcess)
@ObservedObject var myRequestsViewModel: ListViewModel = ListViewModel(listType: .myRequests)
@ObservedObject var settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel = SettingsViewModel()

@State var navTitle: String = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        TabView(selection: self.$viewModel.tabBarSelection) {
            ListView(viewModel: self.toProcessViewModel)
                .tabItem {
                    R.image.tabBar.toProcess
                    Text("tabbar.title.approval".localized)
                }
                .tag(0)
            
            ListView(viewModel: self.myRequestsViewModel)
                .tabItem {
                    R.image.tabBar.myRequests
                    Text("tabbar.title.myRequests".localized)
                }
                .tag(1)
            
            PasswordView()
                .tabItem {
                    R.image.tabBar.password
                    Text("tabbar.title.password".localized)
                }
                .tag(2)
                .commonRedimBackground()
            
            SettingsView(viewModel: self.settingsViewModel)
                .tabItem {
                    R.image.tabBar.settings
                    Text("tabbar.title.settings".localized)
                }
                .tag(3)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(navTitle), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(navigationBarHidden)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .accentColor(R.color.redimBlue)
    }
    .toast(isPresented: self.$viewModel.showingToast, text: self.viewModel.toastTitle, image: self.viewModel.toastImage, backgroundColor: self.viewModel.toastBackgroundColor)
    .bottomSheet(isPresented: self.$viewModel.showingBottomSheet, view: self.viewModel.bottomSheetView)
    .alert(isPresented: self.$viewModel.showingAlert) {
        Alert(title: Text(self.viewModel.alertTitle), message: Text(self.viewModel.alertMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("general.understand".localized)))
    }
    .onReceive(self.viewModel.$tabBarSelection) { tag in
        switch tag {
            case 0:
                navTitle = "tabbar.title.approval".localized
            case 1:
                navTitle = "tabbar.title.myRequests".localized
            case 2:
                navTitle = "" //"tabbar.title.password".localized - UIKit View - remove after switching to SwiftUI
            case 3:
                navTitle = "tabbar.title.settings".localized
            default:
                navTitle = "SELECTION_ERROR"
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Edit: The only thing that worked so far, but I'm not really happy with that solution**

```
struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel

@ObservedObject var toProcessViewModel: ListViewModel = ListViewModel(listType: .toProcess)
@ObservedObject var myRequestsViewModel: ListViewModel = ListViewModel(listType: .myRequests)
@ObservedObject var settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel = SettingsViewModel()

@State var uuid: UUID = UUID()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        TabView(selection: self.$viewModel.tabBarSelection) {
            ListView(viewModel: self.toProcessViewModel)
                .tabItem {
                    R.image.tabBar.toProcess
                    Text("tabbar.title.approval".localized)
                }
                .tag(0)
            
            ListView(viewModel: self.myRequestsViewModel)
                .tabItem {
                    R.image.tabBar.myRequests
                    Text("tabbar.title.myRequests".localized)
                }
                .tag(1)
            
            PasswordView()
                .tabItem {
                    R.image.tabBar.password
                    Text("tabbar.title.password".localized)
                }
                .tag(2)
                .commonRedimBackground()
            
            SettingsView(viewModel: self.settingsViewModel)
                .tabItem {
                    R.image.tabBar.settings
                    Text("tabbar.title.settings".localized)
                }
                .tag(3)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(navigationBarTitle), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(navigationBarHidden)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .accentColor(R.color.redimBlue)
    }
    .id(uuid)
    .toast(isPresented: self.$viewModel.showingToast, text: self.viewModel.toastTitle, image: self.viewModel.toastImage, backgroundColor: self.viewModel.toastBackgroundColor)
    .bottomSheet(isPresented: self.$viewModel.showingBottomSheet, view: self.viewModel.bottomSheetView)
    .alert(isPresented: self.$viewModel.showingAlert) {
        Alert(title: Text(self.viewModel.alertTitle), message: Text(self.viewModel.alertMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("general.understand".localized)))
    }
    .onReceive(self.viewModel.$tabBarSelection) { _ in
        self.uuid = UUID()
    }
}
}

private extension ContentView { // For navigation
    var navigationBarTitle: String {
        switch viewModel.tabBarSelection {
            case 0:
                return "tabbar.title.approval".localized
            case 1:
                return "tabbar.title.myRequests".localized
            case 2:
                return "" //"tabbar.title.password".localized - UIKit View - remove after switching to SwiftUI
            case 3:
                return "tabbar.title.settings".localized
            default:
                return "SELECTION_ERROR"
        }
    }
    
    var navigationBarHidden: Bool {
        switch self.viewModel.tabBarSelection {
            case 2:
                return true
            default:
                return false
        }
    }
}
```

Minimal, Reproducible Example that strangely works

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        TabView(selection: self.$viewModel.tabBarSelection) {
            Text("Tag0")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    Text("tabbar.title.settings")
                }
                .tag(0)
            
            Text("Tag1")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    Text("tabbar.title.settings")
                }
                .tag(1)
            
            Text("Tag2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    Text("tabbar.title.settings")
                }
                .tag(2)
            
            Text("Tag3")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    Text("tabbar.title.settings")
                }
                .tag(3)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(navigationBarTitle))
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
}
```

**ContentViewModel**

```
final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabBarSelection: Int = 0
}
```

**ContentView-Extension**

```
private extension ContentView { // For navigation
    var navigationBarTitle: String {
        switch viewModel.tabBarSelection {
            case 0:
                return "title.approval"
            case 1:
                return "title.myRequests"
            case 2:
                return "title.password"
            case 3:
                return "title.settings"
            default:
                return "SELECTION_ERROR"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is causing a redraw when the NavigationTitle changes. You need some sort of "State" variable that holds it, and then change that variable in the switch statement. Your best best is probably to use a `.onReceive()` to listen for changes in the model, and then change your state variable in a `Switch` in there.

Comment: This way is not working. Edited ContentView is in the question under Edit YrB

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.onReceive($viewModel.tabBarSelection)`? You haven't put up a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can't test it ourselves.

Comment: If I do it like that, the tabBarSelection is @Binding, will try pul mrp here asap.

Comment: Minimal, Reproducible Example added, this strangely works. I'm super confused tbh. Just before I forget about it, the previous project is all setup for iOS 14.0+, this example was run on target iOS 15.0+. All on XCode 13.1 (13A1030d)

Comment: Then you don't have an MRE. Trying setting it to iOS 14 and run on 15.